# iOSCheck if uislider value is increasing or decreasing.

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider

how would one check wether or not a slider's value is increasing or decreasing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know I should use a temporary value, but nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TESTED CODE : 100% WORKS**

.h

```
float lastSlidedValue;


-(IBAction)sliderMoving:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)sliderValueDidChanged:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueDidChanged:(id)sender{//UIControlEventTouchUpInside connected method


    UISlider *sliderr=(UISlider*)sender;


    lastSlideValue=sliderr.value;


}

-(IBAction)sliderMoving:(id)sender{//UIControlEventValueChanged connected method


    UISlider *sliderr=(UISlider*)sender;


    if (lastSlideValue < sliderr.value) {

        NSLog(@"big");      

    }
    else if (lastSlideValue == sliderr.value) {
        NSLog(@"equal");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"low");

    }


}
```

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop

Answer (score 0):

You would be adding a target and writing a selector for your slider. So keep track of slider.value in that selector and keep comparing with the previous slider.value. The selector would be called everytime the value of slider changes (UIControlEventValueChanged)

Answer (score 0):

You can set minimum and maximum value for slider during initialization whom you can understand whether slider is increasing or decreasing

Code is:

```
Slider.maximumValue=10;
Slider.minimumValue=0;
```